# Why is one's place of birth even mentioned in a passport?

Tags: passports

I was discussing this with someone and we couldn't agree on anything... why is it so vital to have one's place of birth on a passport?  Are officials trying to judge whether you were involved in "terrorist" activities in the past since you were born in country that has problems?  For instance, my friend came to Canada as soon as she was born; she has never been back to her place of birth...if the governments want to "track" you it would be not useful in this case since her whole life has been in Canada.  What is the official purpose of being made to state your place of birth on your passport?  And, if you choose not to...you will be hassled apparently...anybody know?

Edit: I have read the response to the "similar" question but it doesn't state whether one has a choice to exclude their birth place worldwide & what are the consequences if they do...?

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with terrorism... passports have been standardized for quite a lot longer than the current "terrorism" scare.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes I know the birth place was used prior to terrorism which is why I put it in quotations...couldn't think of another example just then which is why I'm curious as to the official reasons. :-)

Comment: I think it's to make it slightly easier to distinguish between two persons with the same name, but nowhere near sure enough to make an answer.

Comment: In addtion to date of birth, height, hair colo(u)r and distingiushing features? Th emore, the merrier, I guess